# AS3 to Generate Dynamic SWF?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Is it possible, using AS3, to programmatically generate a .swf file? What my little app does is load a bunch of images, using FileReference, now I want to compile them into a stand-alone swf that the user can download (the swf will be a slideshow).

[edit]

There seems to be some mis-understanding of what I am asking. I want to have one compiled swf from which the user may select some images and press a button whereby the swf will create and compile a second swf containing said images. As this is a stand-alone app, there will be no server-side interaction.

What I am thinking is that there will be a string representing a dynamic class. When the user selects their images the appropriate embed tags are added to this string, which is then compiled and saved to the user's desktop.

So my question is, can a compiled swf generate and compile a second swf?

Comment: creating a swf file server-side is the easy part, but to dynamically `[Embed]` the uploaded photos into a compiled swf is what is going to cause you problems.  dynamically loading the uploaded images from code isn't going to embed then so they won't be present when the user downloads the slideshow swf.

Comment: You should look how FlashDevelop compile projects and read .as3proj file in text editor . It might bring You some ideas

Comment: It's defintiely possible... I've dynamically compiled swfs server side to embed fonts before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this library, this allows you to create a .swf at runtime.
https://github.com/claus/as3swf

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to do server side, by generating the relevant code and running  the as3 compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't investigated the package thoroughly, but the [As3Eval](http://eval.hurlant.com/) library seems to be doing what you're asking - realtime compilation of AS3 into executable bytecode (on the client with no server interaction).  Check out the [demo](http://eval.hurlant.com/demo/#).

I'm not sure it would support image embedding - perhaps you could encode the image data as a base64 string in your dynamically built source code.

Comment: That looks very close to what I want. I shall have a play with it later to see if it is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [swfmill](http://swfmill.org/), a command-line tool to create SWF files from XML documents.

It's not well documented but for basic usages (such as creating asset libraries) you should find what you need.