# Create SWF video of images through Adobe Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4, flash-builder4.5

I don't know whether it's the right place to put this up. But I've been trying from past 12 hours and haven't found anything related.

1. I'm creating a Adobe AIR project (which'll run on desktop), it'll ask for image locations on the local pc.
2. After the user is done selecting images. I want to output a SWF video (slideshow) of the selected images.

How to do the second step. Please guide. I want to create an output file (SWF) from my AIR Flex Desktop Application.

Comment: I wrote a ActionScript Class - it extends Sprite and on setting it as Default Application & running, it creates a SWF with its name. This SWF is similar to what I want.

Although I am unable to create an object of this on a button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did :

1. Install the as3 compiler (mxmlc)
2. Run the command mxmlc.exe sample.as3 using NativeProcess

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/claus/as3swf to compile SWFs at runtime...

This individual seems to have had a similar issue [AS3 to Generate Dynamic SWF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266437/as3-to-generate-dynamic-swf)

Comment: Sorry but it didn't worked for me. So I did this alternative, I installed the as3 compiler and called it on the command line to compile my generated as3 to swf.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following options from [SWFtools](http://www.swftools.org/)

> **JPEG2SWF** Takes one or more JPEG pictures and generates a SWF slideshow from them. Supports motion estimation compression (h.263) for better compression of video sequences.
>
> **PNG2SWF** Like JPEG2SWF, only for PNGs.
>
> **GIF2SWF** Converts GIFs to SWF. Also able to handle animated gifs.