# Can I make a swf template and output swf's with little changes in the actionscript?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

I want to make a system that lets the user fill in a form where he specifies a database name, and uploads a background picture.

Then, I want to create a swf file with the background picture and an urlrequest from a template swf file.

The only problem is, I don't think there is a way to make an swf file without doing it manually, anyone knows a way to achieve this?

Just to be clear, I know how to make everything except how to output an swf file manually.

I have a little bit of difficulty with formulating my question, so feel free to ask for additional information. :)

Basically i'm looking for a server side as3 compiler.

Comment: Why don't you do that from one single SWF, adding an uploaded pic as a background and the URLRequest as the content?

Comment: I want to have a template actionscript or swf file, and send a swf file (and only a swf file) to the user with an unique URLRequest and a embedded background.

Answer (score 0):

quick google for "server side SWF generation" gave me this [link](https://code.google.com/p/serversideswf/) (among others) also I'm sure there is a [class to create SWF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266437/as3-to-generate-dynamic-swf) same as there is to generate PDF's from within SWF's.

Comment: Thanks, but the 1st link is for as2, and i'm using as3. With the second link i can't seem to get anything to work.